# Cluster analysis for a whole sample and subgroups

Tags: clustering, latent-class

I used Latent Gold for cluster analysis of a sample (N=~3000). Then I used the same variables to cluster a the two subgroups that constitute the sample. It performed well for one subgroup, but not for the other: BIC(LL) didn't reach a low point and the % change in L2 continued to grow steadily.
Have any of you experienced something similar? Could it be that the whole sample and one subgroup could be clustered but not the second (largest) subgroup?